# Spring-WS: LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-ws

I have an application that use spring-mvc and hibernate.
To avoid Hibernate lazy initialization exception in mvc controllers I use succesfully the solution exposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992772/spring-opensessioninviewinterceptor-doesnt-work).
Now i have to do the same (if possible) in spring-ws services that are affected by the same issue.
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467290/hibernate-session-handling-in-spring-web-services) trick with no luck.

Any Ideas?
Is there a similar OpenSessionInViewInterceptor to put in web-services interceptors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution,
just specify OpenSessionInViewFilter in web.xml and filter the webservices path with url-pattern `/ws/*`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```